# How do I get this simple ffmpeg command to work in Automator?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, shell-script, automator, code

I'm having trouble getting a simple Automator shell script to work. I'm trying to get an ffmpeg command line to run a task on a file that is dropped onto the application icon.

This is what I've done:

1. Launched Automator.app.
2. Created a new service with service receives files or folders in any application.
3. Added a Run Shell Script action.
4. Applied the following script:

[image: Script]

5. Saved my workflow as both service and application.

When I drop a file onto the app I get this:

[image: Error]

When I run the workflow in Automator I get this:
[image: Run in automator]

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot a semicolon. Try:

```
for f in "$@";
```

Comment: Thank you Radu, I will give this a go as soon as I'm back on that machine later today. Appreciate the feedback.